# How can I disable emoji auto-replacement?

Tags: macos, keyboard, emoji

I've recently upgraded to macOS Sonoma 14.0. Something that's driving me mad is this new emoji auto-replace suggestion menu.

### Problem

Here's the message I'm trying to compose:

> Happy birthday to our tree!

Here's what macOS 14 wants me to write when I use the emoji shortcut:

> Happy birthday to our tree!

[image]

### Question

How do I disable this smaller emoji suggester in favor of the traditional, full dialog?

[image]

### Why?

In this author's opinion, emoji is *punctuation*, not a replacement for nouns. I use emoji to convey the emotion of the sentence, not make cute pictures of various nouns throughout. This smaller menu introduces another click and hasn't suggested the emoji I'd like to see once.

Answer (score 0):

With the small dialog open, press the button(s) again to open the full dialog.

If you open the small dialog with the globe/fn key, press the key again.
If you open the small dialog with ctrl-cmd-space, press that key combination again.

Unfortunately, there appears to be no way to disable the small dialog from appearing first yet. This has also been asked on Reddit, see [Is there a way to turn OFF the new emoji suggestions in Sonoma?](https://www.reddit.com/r/MacOS/comments/16wzdk9/is_there_a_way_to_turn_off_the_new_emoji/).